# Set Custom Category Attribute Custom Value

Tags: magento-1.12

Am creating a new custom category attribute, its a select box with source of `eav/entity_attribute_source_boolea`.

Here is my code

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
   'group' => 'General Information',
   'type' => 'int',
   'label'=> 'Show as link in navigation menu',
   'input' => 'select',
   'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
   'visible' => true,
   'required' => false,
   'user_defined' => true,
   'default' => '1',
   'sort_order' => '1000',
   'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
);
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_category','navigation_link');
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'navigation_link', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

How do I set the default value of the select box to yes? Isin't `"default" => "1"` supposed to do the job?